# How to proxy static files to/from multiple hosts with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two applications running on nginx docker containers, each one is a front-end app, with css, JS, etc.
I need access througth a reverse proxy (nginx in another container),
but the statics files are searched in the proxy container instead of the rigth container (app.local or login.local).

My proxy configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /login {

        rewrite /login(.*) $1 break;

        proxy_pass http://login.local:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /app {

        rewrite /app(.*) $1 break;

        proxy_pass http://app.local:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

My nginx proxy log:

```
192.168.150.13 - - [09/Aug/2016:13:59:13 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
2016/08/09 13:59:13 [error] 334#334: *118 open() "/etc/nginx/html/css/main.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.150.13, server: machine.local, request: "GET /css/main.css?1470692258780 HTTP/1.1", host: "machine.local:7000", referrer: "http://machine.local:7000/login"
192.168.150.13 - - [09/Aug/2016:13:59:13 +0000] "GET /css/main.css?1470692258780 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://machine.local:7000/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: Do you have a location for /css? As right now you are stating anything that starts with /app or /login should be handled by a proxy. You show nothing for /css.

Comment: No, CSS files are inside of own application (container). It supposed the CSS (all static files) must be proxied by application's location too.

Comment: But you are calling GET /css/main.css not for example /login/css/main.css so nginx doesn't know where to go with that request

Comment: Yes that is the point. I want each app serves its static files.avoiding the 'login' prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Nginx Http Sub Module to modify the proxied content to add the prefix to returned content urls.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html